# How to 'uncheckout' in SVN

Tags: svn

I am trying to uncheckout certain repository in my SVN.

for example:

I did

```
svn co svn://address/project1/test test
```

I want to '`uncheckout`' the project and did something like

```
svn co svn://address/project1/test project1-test
```

Are there any better or faster way to do this? Thanks a log!

Comment: 0_o What do you mean by "uncheckout"?

Comment: sorry I mean remove it from my svn control and recheck out again with the correct folder path.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  Rename the folder `test` to `project1-test`.

The name of the directory containing the full checkout is unimportant to Subversion.

Answer (score 3):

If all you want to do is rename your local directory, that's all you have to do:

```
mv test project1-test
```

Done.  SVN doesn't care what the outer directory's name is.